# Tableview controller loading array error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

i have a table VC in which i have pass static array of list and when we click the item in an array it open its view controller, Now i have written another view controller at index 9 but when i run the app it shows me error of *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'.  Indexing is fine but i don't know why it is coming. My code is,

```
     NSString *success= [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"];
    if ([success isEqual:@"Success"]) {
        NSString *string1 = [successDefaults stringForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"Name is %@",string1);

         LeftMenuData1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:string1,@"Home",@"Show Franchiser",@"AboutUs",@"Logout",@"Contact Us",@"Wanted",@"Terms&Conditions",@"Share App",@"View Properties",@"Chat", nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }else{

        LeftMenuData1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"Home",@"Show Franchiser",@"AboutUs",@"Login/Register",@"Contact Us",@"Wanted",@"Terms&Conditions",@"Share App",@"Chat",nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

}

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [LeftMenuData1 count];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[LeftMenuData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[LeftMenuDataImages1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float height = 40;

    NSUserDefaults *successDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *str111=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[successDefaults valueForKey:@"currentUser"]];
    int currentLoginStatus = [str111 intValue];
    if(currentLoginStatus == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        height = 0;

    return height;
}

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell.textLabel.text);

    AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSUserDefaults *successDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[LeftMenuData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    if (row == 0) {

        NSString *str111=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[successDefaults valueForKey:@"currentUser"]];

        int currentLoginStatus = [str111 intValue];
        if(currentLoginStatus == 1)
        {

            UpViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Up"];
            UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];

            [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

        } else if(currentLoginStatus == 2)
        {
            UserProfileViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profile"];
            UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];

            [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];
        }
    }else if(row == 1){

        HomePageViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];

        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

    }else if (row == 2){

        FransFormViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"frans"];

        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];



        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];



    }else if (row == 3){
        AboutUsViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutUs"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

    }else if (row == 4){

        NSUserDefaults *successDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ([[successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
            [successDefaults setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"Success"];
            [successDefaults setObject:@"0" forKey:@"currentUser"];

            [successDefaults synchronize];
            [successDefaults synchronize];
            [app.drawer toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];

        }else{
            GeneralLoginViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"General"];
            UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
            [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

        }

    }else if(row == 5){
        ContactInfoViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactInfo"];

        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];

        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];
    }else if (row == 6){
        WantedViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WantedViewController"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];
    }else if (row == 7){

        Terms_ConditionViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Terms"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];
    }else if (row == 8){

        ShareViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Share"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

    }
   else if (row==9) {
       TestChat *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Chat"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }

    else if (row == 10){
        NSUserDefaults *successDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ([[successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"] isEqualToString:@"Success"]){

        ViewPersonalTableViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewProps"];
        UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:presales];
        [app.drawer setCenterViewController:nav withCloseAnimation:true completion:nil];

        }


    }else{
    }

}
```

Comment: Post less code.

Comment: when your first portion of code  executed ?

Comment: What is the number count of LeftMenuDataImages1?

Comment: my code was working fine till i haven't added index 9 after adding another option at index 9 to show TestChat view controller it starts showing me this error, When i remove TestChat vc from index 9 and gives index 9 to below VC it shows no error. @iPatel

Comment: its 10 dear. @YogendraGirase

Comment: If this line `cell.imageView.image =...` is causing the crash, I guess that `[LeftMenuDataImages1 count]` and `[LeftMenuData1 count]` are different. Avoid using two arrays. But please, try to locate the line that is causing the crash.

Comment: i have 10 images 10items in an array and shows all of them but facing this error. @YogendraGirase

Comment: It's happen because LeftMenuData1 has different count of items based on `  NSString *success= [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"];
    if ([success isEqual:@"Success"])` condition manage it.

Comment: but i want to shows the Chat item in both condition whether [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"]; is success or not. @iPatel

Comment: got it ur point is fine. @iPatel

Answer (score 1):

In the start of your code, you check if a string is equal to `"Success"`.
If it **is**, you create the array `LeftMenuData1` with **11** elements, including `string1` and `"View Properties"`. If it is **not** `"Success"`, then you tell that array to have **10** elements, including `@""`(instead of `string1` but **no** `"View Properties"`.

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you return the number of elements in `LeftMenuData1` which is either **10** or **11**.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (which will be called either 10 or 11 times) you create each cell with this text: `cell.textLabel.text=[LeftMenuData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. This is fine, because the `LeftMenuData1` already has the same number of elements as there are indexes in your `tableView`.
**But** you also do this: `cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[LeftMenuDataImages1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` which tries to access **another** array (`LeftMenuDataImages1`), which (by your code) does not change its number of elements based on `"Success"`. Since this is crashing, I am assuming that `LeftMenuDataImages1` **always** has **10** elements.

If this is true, the crash is happening only when `"Success"` is `true`, because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` tries to get the eleventh element in `LeftMenuDataImages1`, which only has 10 elements.

Even if you add an eleventh element to you `Images`-array, they will be wrong, because the index of the last elements are wrong. You need to set `LeftMenuDataImages1` to two different arrays based on `"Success"` in the exact same way you set `LeftMenuData1` to be different based on `"Success"`.

E.g like this:

```
 NSString *success= [successDefaults valueForKey:@"Success"];
if ([success isEqual:@"Success"]) {
    NSString *string1 = [successDefaults stringForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog(@"Name is %@",string1);

    LeftMenuData1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:string1,@"Home",@"Show Franchiser",@"AboutUs",@"Logout",@"Contact Us",@"Wanted",@"Terms&Conditions",@"Share App",@"View Properties",@"Chat", nil];
    LeftMenuDataImages1 =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:someImageName,@"HomeImage",@"ShowFranchiserImage",@"AboutUsImage",@"LogoutImage",@"ContactUsImage",@"WantedImage",@"Terms&ConditionsImage",@"ShareAppImage",@"ViewPropertiesImage",@"ChatImage", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}else{

    LeftMenuData1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"Home",@"Show Franchiser",@"AboutUs",@"Login/Register",@"Contact Us",@"Wanted",@"Terms&Conditions",@"Share App",@"Chat",nil];
    LeftMenuDataImages1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"EmptyImage",@"HomeImage",@"ShowFranchiserImage",@"AboutUsImage",@"Login/RegisterImage",@"ContactUsImage",@"WantedImage",@"Terms&ConditionsImage",@"ShareAppImage",@"ChatImage",nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Just insert your own image names.